# Dealing with special characters PHP Webdriver

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send a special character (é) using sendkeys, example:

```
$webdriver->findElement(element)->sendKeys('Sévigny');
```

and its returning an error

#4 /file.php(136): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement->sendKeys('S\xE9vigny')

#5 in /vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php on line 114

I tried decoding the character first, but it didn't help. I also saw solutions that mention WebUtility.HtmlDecode, but I'm not sure how this is done PHP webdriver and there's no mention of it in documentation

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$webdriver->findElement(element)->sendKeys(utf8_encode('Sévigny'));
```

Comment: damn... and I was decoding this whole time... will accept in 6 mins. thank you!!